# @Stateless EJB clashing when opening a new tab for the same web application

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I have created a generic @stateless EJB (LoadEntityEJBImpl) that is used for all of my JPA transactions.
Im using the ejb-jar.xml to inject the entityManager without annotations so that I can control which persistance resource is being used for each application.

The problem that I have is that in all of my web applications that I have used this EJB when I call one transaction on a page and then open a new tab to another page The EJB sometimes clashes and throws an exception.

I think that what might be happening is that when I hit the first page the EJB is created (if none exist or none available) 
Then when its finished being used it goes back into the EJB pool (made available for other requests).
Then I open my new tab and the EJB is pulled out of the EJB pool with the previous parameters set against it.

returnedToPark is a column in my orders entity but im not selecting for this table in any way shape or form, including by lazy and egar loading.

The exception is below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [returnedToPark] against path
 at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:120)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:229)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:200)
 at au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJBImpl.generateFilterPredicates(LoadEntityEJBImpl.java:317)
 at au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJBImpl.generateFilterPredicatesWithDates(LoadEntityEJBImpl.java:157)
 at au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJBImpl.createCriteriaQuery(LoadEntityEJBImpl.java:123)
 at au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJBImpl.buildEntityObjectsQuery(LoadEntityEJBImpl.java:110)
 at au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJBImpl.getEntityObjectsByRange(LoadEntityEJBImpl.java:806)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor184.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
 at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:180)
 at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:99)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:80)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:181)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:268)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:263)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:86)
 at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:303)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.getEntityObjectsByRange(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.jsp.operations.container.schedule.containerScheduleIndex_jsp._jspService(containerScheduleIndex_jsp.java:1584)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the content of the ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <module-name>PKWebapp</module-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session id="PKWebappID">
            <ejb-name>LoadEntityEJBPKWebapp</ejb-name>
            <mapped-name>LoadEntityEJBPKWebappMapped</mapped-name>
            <business-remote>au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJB</business-remote>
            <ejb-class>au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJBImpl</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <persistence-context-ref id="PKIDWebapp">
                <description>PKWebapp reference</description>
                <persistence-context-ref-name>LoadEntityEJBImplRefNamePKWebapp/entityManager</persistence-context-ref-name>
                <persistence-unit-name>PKWebappDS</persistence-unit-name>
                <persistence-context-type>Transaction</persistence-context-type>
                <injection-target>
                    <injection-target-class>au.com.xxx.ejb.LoadEntityEJBImpl</injection-target-class>
                    <injection-target-name>entityManager</injection-target-name>
                </injection-target>
            </persistence-context-ref>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Due to privacy I can't give out the Full code sample of the LoadEntityEJBImpl but I can provide a small sample.

```
@Stateless
public class LoadEntityEJBImpl<T> implements LoadEntityEJB<T>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6359834805546452108L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoadEntityEJBImpl.class.getName());
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private Class<T> entityClass;
    @Resource
    private EJBContext context;

@Override
public EntityManager getEM() {
if (entityManager == null) {
    entityManager = getFactory().createEntityManager();
}
return entityManager;
}


@Override
public EntityManagerFactory getFactory() {
return factory;
}

public void setFactory(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
this.factory = factory;
}
...
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Why are you using EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory?  How is the EMF used?  Are you overwriting the entityManager injection with an unmanaged EM?

Comment: From my understanding we are not using the EntityManagerFactory except for in our JUnit tests.

Comment: I guess that's reasonable (but how does factory get set for your unit test? You might as well use a `public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em)` method).  Anyway, I don't have any other guesses for how you're getting data from an unrelated query, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In your stack trace I see that some container scheduler ( at org.apache.jsp.operations.container.schedule.containerScheduleIndex_jsp._jspService(containerScheduleIndex_jsp.java:1584)) runs the method getEntityObjectsByRange ( at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.getEntityObjectsByRange(Unknown Source)). Check your deployments in glassfish, and clear possible old deployments from it.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, this made no difference at all... Any other suggestions?
I should note that I'm using TomEE 1.6.0 as the container

Comment: Hhmmm. My assumption about glassfish was wrong... Can you tell what class has getEntityObjectsByRange?

Comment: Yes thats my LoadEntityEJBImpl, as I mentioned it is a generic class that is  calculating the where clause dynamically it works perfectly except for this problem that Im having. If I wasn't injecting the persistence context (EntityManager) do you think I'd still have the same problem?

Comment: I suppose  would have no difference. Can you check, is problem attribute exists in managed database?

Comment: Alexander, the attribute that its complaining about is associated with a totally different table... thats the whole problem.... When I open one page its selecting from the table that contains the **returnedToPark** attribute, when I open a new tab the EJB is reused and still retains the information about the first table for some reason??? the desired effect is that it should not be retaining any information at all about any other requests that are being made.... its almost like its treating the entityManager as a static field being shared across all instances.

Comment: I see root of the problem in your own CDI implementation (for example, entitymanager injection). Can you turn to standard? Am I right your are using the same application in one server with different settings\options? What is the barier between application? Is application with problem setting work fine without others? SLB instanсe is not shared between different application by default, and forgot about state at the end of lifecycle.

Comment: Im currently using the one EJB in multiple applications, I will try and remove the config from the injection process and let the container handle it. I'll try this over the weekend.